# Splicing mesh plumbing pipe

Tags: water, pipe, sink

I installed a new faucet. I replaced the old PVC pipe that connected the faucet to the water line with the supplied pipe.

The supplied pipes are not PVC. They're instead covered in some kind of mesh.

Previously, the old PVC pipe was cut and joined to a splitter that channeled water to the under-sink filtration system.

Is it possible to cut this mesh-type pipe and join it to a splitter as well? What's underneath the mesh? Will the mesh interfere with anything?

### Pictures ##3

The first picture shows the old hose. Note how it's all PVC - no fancy mesh or whatever. The black hose goes to the filtration system.

The second picture is a close up of the T fitting. What kind of T fitting is this? It seems as if all the hoses were pressed into the T fitting - there doesn't appear to be anything that can be unscrewed. What would I look for at the hardware store? How would I remove the black hose? I tried pulling it out but that's not getting anywhere.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture would allow us to try to give some more detailed advice.

Answer (score 2):

Do not cut the mesh on flexible water line connections. The mesh is there to protect the internal "rubber" hose and also should help to keep the hose from bursting under unexpected high pressure situations. If you need to make a junction for the water filtration system then you should be using two shorter mesh covered connection hoses and affix a T fitting in between them. The branch of the T goes off to the filter unit. Note that it sometimes takes a number of various adapter fittings to make up the compatible T assembly depending upon the parts available at your supplier.

Answer (score 1):

The white "T" fitting is called a push fit connector. The white lip where the 1/4 inch hose goes in needs to be pushed the opposite way that you're pulling the hose...e.g. push it down with one hand and pull the hose with the other.  To reconnect you just need to make sure the hose end is nice and straight then push in fully - it will grab.